# Lightswitch HTML databinding to a details collection

Tags: data-binding, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a simple master/details relationship where one order can have multiple revenue allocations. The order has a collection that contains these.

I want to sum a property in my revenue allocation objects and ensure that it adds up to my order total. However, if I databind on the count property of the allocations collection this gets called when you first add an empty object and not when that object has been populated. So an empty allocation is added at the time the "Add allocation" screen is created and the databind function called. That of course means that when the save button on the "Add allocation" screen is clicked, the databind function isn't called again.

Anyone got any ideas? I basically want my databind function to be called when the save button is clicked in the "add screen" and not before.

This is the HTML client - NOT Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the solution would be to use an OData query to get your aggregate data within the databinding function of the save button - or perhaps a separate button (e.g. "Tally Order Totals").  Exactly how you do that?  A bit too hard for me to answer right now, but start with a new button TallyOrderTotals and a new data field for your total.  Edit the post_render event for TallyOrderTotals and lookup the allocations in the javascript in which you data bind the value of the new data field.

Somewhere you will need a piece of code that looks something like this:

```
myapp.activeDataWorkSpace.<datasource>.RevenueAllocations
    .filter("OrderID eq " + msls._toODataString(<orderID>, ":String"))
    .execute()
    .then(function (result) {
        // assign the result somewhere
    }
```

I'm not saying that's something you can cut-and-paste - but definitely look at the [msls.js documentation](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a2935144-ed60-4750-ba1b-b39d25f403cf) and see what you can do with querying your data inside the event context.

One quick point however - if you only need to calculate that total as a verification step, consider doing it in the SaveExecuting() event on the server side.  This will allow you to throw an exception back up the tree to your HTML page which the msls.js script should render on the client side.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Many thanks Ozziemedes - will let you know how I get on!